# CSS div naming grammar

Tags: css

Can you use the word div to name a div class? or id?

for example:

`#div.leftcol`

or does it just get seen as

`#leftcol`

Comment: You should clarify whether you mean setting the id or class of a div element to the string "div" in HTML: `<div id="div"></div>` or `<div class="div"></div>`, or referencing the element type in conjunction with the id or class in CSS: `div.className{}` or `div#idName{}`.

Comment: You can, but really... why on earth would you want to? Surely only ever going to add to confusion.

Answer (score 3):

The browser will see that as `<div id="div" class="leftcol"></div>`

Comment: so when I start a div I would say:

Answer (score 2):

I don't follow what you mean, but I think what you're asking is can you use the word `div` to apply a class to `div` elements. If that's what you mean, then yes you can, and you do it exactly as you have shown in your question:

`div.leftcol { color: red }`

That style would be applied to all elements of type `div` with class `leftcol`. Without the `div` part, the style would apply to any element with class `leftcol`, regardless of what type of element it is:

`.leftcol { color: red }`

**Edit** now the question has been edited...

After the edit to your question, it makes a bit more sense (I think). Your first example would apply to an element with an `id` of `div` and a class of `leftcol`:

`<div id="div" class="leftcol"></div>`

The second example would apply to an element with an `id` of `leftcol`:

`<div id="leftcol"></div>`

**Or** if you are simply asking whether `div` is a some sort of reserved word in CSS, no, it's not, so feel free to use it as an identifier. However, that could get confusing (for example, you could end up with selectors like `div.div #div`)

Answer (score 1):

can you provide an example?

you can use `<div class="leftcol"> left content </div>`

and then in your css `.leftcol { background:red; }`

you can address it either div.leftcol or just simple .leftcol

Answer (score 0):

As in?

```
<div id="div.leftcol">Some content</div>
```

While it may work for HTML and Javascript it should cause a problem if you try to style it in a CSS stylesheet. As I am sure you know the following

```
div.leftcol {
   color: #efefef;
}
```

means "Set the text color to #efefef for any div element that has leftcol as a class name" so it would not work. I have no idea if

```
div.div.leftcol {
   color: #efefef;
}
```

would work but that is just ugly...